# Makefile multiple sources ouputs variable expansion

Tags: makefile

suppose `CC` variable is a compiling command and we don't need any additional flags. Simple part of makefile compiling main.c and next.c to main.o and next.o:

```
all: main.o next.o

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```

Now suppose I would like to have output files in variable:

```
all: $(OBJ)

OBJ = main.o next.o

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```

Of course it won't work. I understand why but I can't find solution. Can you help me?

Comment: Umm... you just put the variable assignment `OBJ = main.o next.o` before the variable use `all: $(OBJ)`... am I missing something?  You say you understand why it doesn't work; what is your understanding of why it doesn't work?  And why can't you just reorder these lines?

Comment: @MadScientist : My understanding was: Makefile searches for dependencies `OBJ` and finds it and expand to mani.o and next.o but doesn't know that it shall create these files. I haven't notice that order of lines in makefile is significant. Makefile is a magic for me. Thank you for help!

Comment: Exactly when order is important can be confusing.  However, you need to define variables before they are used in either target or prerequisite contexts (in your example, `all : $(OBJ)` is a rule where `all` is the target and `$(OBJ)` is the prerequisite).  Full details are here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html

Comment: BTW, your understanding of the error wasn't quite right.  Because you used the variable `OBJ` before it was defined, it expanded to the empty string.  So your makefile effectively was just `all: ` and hence make didn't know it needed to build anything.  If you define the variable first, make expands that to `all: main.o next.o` and then make knows what it needs to do.

Comment: @MadScientist: I didn't analyze it in that way. I thought if I have: `all: $(OBJ)` it's a `target : [dependencies]` and if `dependencies` isn't defined it will be searched in makefile.

Comment: That's true if it's an explicit dependency: those don't have to be defined in order (except the first one in the file will be the one built by default).  But macros are different: they are expanded using text replacement, basically, and the results are parsed as prerequisites.  See the link to the manual I provided above.